# Specify DataFrame name in Python using defined function, for use within another defined function

Tags: python

Trying to create a function to specify the name of a DataFrame, so it can be used within another function. Tried a few different approaches, but this is a simplified version of what I have now.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'var1': [1, 2, 3], 'var2': [1, 2, 3]}
h_df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)


def hh(wave):
    hh = 'h_' + wave
    return hh


def table(wave):
    hh_data = hh(wave)
    hh_data["new_var"] = hh_data["var1"]*hh_data["var2"]
    return table


table = table("df1")

print(table)
```

This gives the error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

The result I am expecting is that hh_data uses a DataFrame named h_df1. Looking for a way to automate which DataFrame is picked up. It's part of a more complex system.

Comment: hh_data is just string, not dict.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want is Python built-in [globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) functions, which returns a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. For example, `globals()["h_df1"]` will return the `h_df1` variable. Thus, you can do

```py
def table(wave):
    hh_data = globals()[hh(wave)]
    hh_data["new_var"] = hh_data["var1"]*hh_data["var2"]
    return table
```

Comment: When I do this using separate files for each function, I get the error: KeyError: 'h_df1'

Comment: @an1uk Well, From the doc, *This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the module from which it is called)*. `globals()` doesn't work with separate files.

Answer (score 0):

- hh_data is just string, not dict.
- if you want to create new column, you can try below code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pandas as pd

    data1 = {'var1': [1, 2, 3], 'var2': [1, 2, 3]}
    h_df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

    h_df1['new_var'] = h_df1["var1"] * h_df1["var2"]

    print(h_df1.head(5))
```